# What sorting algorithms are best when a lot of items can take only a small amount of different values

Tags: algorithm, performance, sorting

We could have solved our problem with a hash table but for technical reasons which I won’t develop here (it’s for a student project) we need to perform the sorting on a very large array.

So here is my question: let’s say that you have a very very large array which contains only a small amount of different values. (For instance the array generated by the following Ruby code: `a = []; 10.upto(20) { |i| a += [i]*500_000 }; a = a.shuffle`)

Is there an algorithm which performs better in this case ?

Comment: [Counting sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) has a time complexity of `O(n + size(input range))`, and, with preprocessing to map unique input values to their sorted rank, can run in time `O(n + #unique values)`, assuming `n` much larger than the number of unique values

Comment: If you can use a hash, then you could do the following (in Ruby). Say `arr = [3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1]; h = arr.tally #=> {3=>1, 1=>3, 2=>2}; keys = h.keys #=> [3, 1, 2]; keys.sort.flat_map { |k| [k]*h[k] } #=> [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3]`. @kcsquared, am I correct in assuming that this is the gist of the "counting sort"?

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yes, it's a standard sort of unique values, followed by the traditional counting sort.

Answer (score -3):

Usually, it doesn't matter what is the amount of different values it can take...
What really matter is the time an algorithms take to sort an array no matter the values in it.
By far the fastest algorithm yet pretty complex is the 3-way quicksort algorithm.
If you a are a begginer I suggest you don't get into algorithm of this complexity, but it is the fastest. Then I suggest you start with the TimSort or the MergeSort. Both of these are considered medium in term of difficulty but are definitely a good method to start your arrays and a quick way too.
You can also get much more information on sorting algorithms here : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sorting-algorithms/

Comment: I read your argument as saying one should pay no attention to the number of unique values in the array, even if that is a tiny fraction of the number of elements in the array. Correct?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What metrics are you using to determine "what really matters for an algorithm"? Do you mean that input distributions don't have a large effect on the time performance of sorting algorithms? If so, it would be great if you could provide a source or reasoning for that claim, as that would be highly surprising.

Comment: I'm not saying one should pay any attention to the number of uniques values in the array. But i'm saying that for the vast majority of well-known and efficient algorithm, it does not  really take in consideration the amount of different unique values.  But input distribution has a lot to do with the quickness of the algorithm. This is what i've seen and understand from what i've read. Feel free to correct me if i'm wrong on that one.

Comment: From what i've seen, the most commonly used metric used to calculate the efficiency of an algorithm is the maximum amount of sort it would need to do to sort the array completely. Like the amount of elements in the array. For example : 3-Way QuickSort is : O(N * log(N)) where ‘N’ is the number of elements in the given array/list or like : Bubble Sort is : O(n*n) where n is the number of elements in the givent array/list.

Comment: Thank you for the clarifications and the comments. I agree with you that by far the most used sorting algorithms are comparison algorithms like quicksort that don't optimize for the number of distinct elements. I think quicksort is also almost always the practical suggestion: it's generic, has good average performance, and is already written for you in any standard library. However, the whole field of non-comparison sorts and integer sorting, such as radix or counting sort, are designed to be theoretically faster for cases such as few unique values, and closer to what was requested here.

Comment: Thank you for the clarifications, I didn't know that, thank you for correcting me !